# AlarmManager adding alarm few times per second on specific devices

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have got a problem with alarmservice - it's set up to go off every hour and it works perfectly fine on my galaxy SII - however, on the wildfire and wildfire S the app hogs the whole system.
After looking at logs, it seems that alarm is added and trigered a few times every second.
I really don't understand why this is happening and more than that it bothers me, how could this problem be device specifc?

Here is what the log says:

`V/AlarmManager(  103): Adding Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app} Jan 12 04:43:35 pm
V/AlarmManager(  103): Alarm triggering: Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app}
V/AlarmManager(  103): Adding Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app} Jan 12 04:43:35 pm
V/AlarmManager(  103): Alarm triggering: Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app}
V/AlarmManager(  103): Adding Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app} Jan 12 04:43:36 pm
V/AlarmManager(  103): Alarm triggering: Alarm{44cf66f8 type 0 weat.heria.app}`

Please help me regarding this.

Edit: here is the code setting the alarm

```
 public void setAlarm(int refreshRate) {
     Intent myIntent = new Intent(WeatheriaActivity.this, AlarmService.class);
     pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(WeatheriaActivity.this, 0,
             myIntent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
     alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.
             getTimeInMillis(), refreshRate, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that's setting the alarms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PendingIntent.getService()` should be passed [a flag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) for its last parameter, not `0`. I'd try fixing that first.

Comment: Well, on first sight it seems that this was the problem indeed. Will need to test it more to be sure. Thanks :)